# Dataset with two unique trends?

Tags: regression, correlation, scatterplot, astronomy

I have a scatterplot displaying one data set that, at first glance, has a weak negative correlation. Upon further inspection, however, it appears that the data set shows two stronger linear trends that seem to separate after a certain threshold. Is it possible for a single dataset to display multiple trends? I assume it would be intrinsic to whatever information you are studying/graphing but I'm not sure if the results are reasonable. Thanks!

[image: Complete Data Set]          [image: Fitted Data Set]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! To what do the dot colors in the right graph correspond? Is there a blue group and a red group, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

I also see two trend lines in your data, but they go in the opposite direction of yours!

[image]

The human brain has an awesome power to find patterns in random data. Without a prior hypothesis (or a covariate that defines two groups of data points), I'd be very wary of defining two lines in a bunch of very scattered points.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible -- you show an example of it happening. Another example would be the relation between height and weight, separately for men and women. If you lumped them all together, there would be a positive trend, but it would be much stronger with sex added as a variable.

This is one of the big advantages of adding covariates to your model.

One key question will be if you can figure out what separates the points on the two lines. If you're just finding things after looking at the data, then that's fishing and has to be done very carefully.  It's also called HARKing (hypothesizing after results are known).

You would need to separate the purely exploratory work from hypothesis testing.